# Find the partial using differentials

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The task is to find $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$ of the function $w = zxe^y + xe^z + ye^z$ with the constraint $x^2y + xy^2 = 1$. Assume $x$ is independent.

So, we first find the differential of the constraint to be $(2x + y^2)dx + (x^2 + 2xy)dy = 0$, from which $dy = \frac{2xy + y^2}{x^2 + 2xy}dx$.

Then, substituting this into the total differential of $w$, we get $dw = (ze^y + e^z)dx + (zxe^y + e^z)dy + (xe^y + xe^z + ye^z)dz$. Key question now:

The latter expression then looks as the following $dw = (0 + e^0)dx + (0 + e^0)(\frac{2xy + y^2}{x^2 + 2xy}) + (xe^y + xe^z + ye^z)$ which after algebraic transformations gives the final $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} = \frac{x^2 + 4xy + y^2}{x^2 + 2xy}$

Why do we make $z = 0$ in the expression for $dw$ above? Is this because it is **not** in the constraint? So, we don't look at the $xz, yz-$planes, just the $xy-$plane?

Comment: I can't figure why z=0, except that this is a mistake. Suppose that w represent a temperature. Then w assign to every point (x,y,z) in the space a temperature. The restriction represent a plane curve in the xy plane, but a cylinder in the xyz space. So, the task, as it is write, is to look the "gradient" of the temperature along the x axis only for the cylinder defined by the restriction. (gradient in the sense of variation of the temperature vs the distance). What you need to equate to zero now is dz, not z and dz. Maybe the problem states somewhere that z=0 as another restriction.

Comment: I had the same approach of equating dz to 0 initially, but there is no constraint in the form z = z(x,y) = constant, whose differential we could make equal to 0.
There is no constraint of z = 0.